# Require confirmation of current user's email before updating database and before send_email_change_email

Tags: users, security, user-meta, profiles, email-verification

I like the core ability for users to update their default "Email" field.

For example username1 can edit their own profile and change their "Email" field from email1@example.com to email2@example.com and click save.

After update, I like that an email that is sent by wordpress core to email1@example.com notifying that the change happened in the database. This email is a courtesy of core's "send_email_change_email" function, and i have not tampered with it.

However, I wish that the database update from email1@example.com to email2@example.com would not happen until a link is clicked in the email that is sent to email1@example.com (e.g. the send_email_change_email).  In other words, I don't like that username1 has the potential to mistype their desired new email address. I want the additional security layer of requiring email1@example.com to accept the change before it happens.  This is a standard in some enterprise applications. The confirmation link should expire after use, and after some time.

What are some options for solving this? Thank you community!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here i will give this a try..

[Confirmation required on email change](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41730/confirmation-required-on-email-change)