# Confirmation required on users email change

Tags: email

This kind of issue was already discussed [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41730/confirmation-required-on-email-change), but the question is 10 yo and none of the answers work, obviously.

Basically, Wordpress already have the function written in /wp-includes/user.php, which is send_confirmation_on_profile_email(), but for some reason it's not an "option" in the settings, or am I missing something?

As far as I know, the confirmation sent to change the profile email is an 'admin-only' thing.
Is there any way to make it work for users too? I'm using Wordpress update 6

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, the confirmation sent to change the profile email is an 'admin-only' thing. Is there any way to make it work for users too? I'm using Wordpress update 6

As far as I understand, this was additionally implemented, in ticket [#16470](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16470) few years ago, for **all single site users** that try to change their own email address.

Comment: following the changelog of the various updates, yes they moved this function from ms.php to user.php, yet there is still no function neither a setting for single site that let you choose that, it's just an automatic email update within the account details page. meanwhile, admin email change works just right and you will receive an email to confirm the updated infos

Comment: It's hooked into `personal_options_update` action [here](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/613cac5a2d809a4078b23945a6c57750bdebd9b0/src/wp-admin/includes/admin-filters.php#L126) and I don't see any admin-only user capability checks in [/wp-admin/user-edit.php](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/b316c8b25fc71920d89ee37ee26609a77b2a305a/src/wp-admin/user-edit.php#L145) that would prevent this from running on all users updating own email and I would expect the current user be able to successfully go through the `edit_user` check there on the current user .

Comment: The unit tests are [here](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/590ca0ff94e958d26e3103114ea22c34f1e2fff9/tests/phpunit/tests/user.php#L1570):

Comment: thank you, I'll take a look at that and update the question accordingly

Comment: I took a look at everything linked, and it seems like they really made the send_confirmation.. an "option", yet I can't find a solution to make it work instead of the function actually sending the email to users, which is send_email_change_email(). Am I missing a setting? or am I delusional?

Comment: Strange, I tested this with a subscriber role and when I changed the email I got an Email Change Request. This worked on a vanilla (single site) 6.0 install with an email logger. I had to confirm the email change via email link.

Comment: yeah, I tried something similar because I thought it was some plugin in conflict with it, but the email was still auto-updated. I'll give it one last chance and create a new staging website and see what happens. thanks for trying